# What does the background color of html element (root element) actually mean?

Tags: html, css

To ask an embarrassing question? Given I never write anything within body element, the height of root element is 0. We will find out the height of root element is 0. When I try to set the background color of this element, the entire page was set to this color.

How the entire page get that color. And how to avoid it.